# Openness of the set of matrices whose upper-left submatrix of size r×r is invertible

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I am reading a proof of why the fixed rank manifold is a smooth embedded manifold of $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. However there was a statement that I was not completly sure of:

The proof argues that given subset $\mathcal{U}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ that consists of matrices whose upper-left submatrix of size r×r is invertible. Then  $\mathcal{U}$ is open in  $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ as its complement—the set of matrices whose
upper-left submatrix has determinant equal to zero—is closed.

The last sentence is what I am not sure of: why is it evident that the set of matrices whose
upper-left submatrix has determinant equal to zero is closed?

Comment: The determinant (of the upper left submatrix) is a continuous function from matrices to reals, so its zero set (or the preimage of any point, or more generally preimage of any closed set) is closed.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Why not an official answer?